# Block a device when it is offline

Tags: android-management-api

Our customer would like to block devices if they've not been communicating with our backend for a long time.

I've checked the `PolicyEnforcementRule` policy setting, but according to the documentation, it only works with a top-level policy. Put it another way, we cannot make it work with the device `STATUS_REPORT` information sent by the Android Management API.

Is there a way to notify the `Android Device Policy` locally, through our Companion App, so that the device can be blocked automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to notify Android Device Policy locally using your companion app. However, we have filed a feature request on your behalf but there is no guarantee when this will be worked on.

I suggest [joining the Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to keep you posted on the latest updates.